# How to assess drug effects using annual death rate data?

Tags: meta-analysis, experiment-design, t-test, relative-risk

I am planning a study to collect data of patients dying after brain infection versus number of cases for the next 5 years in 2 cities where they manage the disease with different drugs.

1. Will a ***year wise t-test be better or year wise Relative Risk of death and meta analysis*** be better to compare the results of the study?
2. I am a beginner in statistics. A word of explanation would benefit me.

The data would look like

```
Year     City 1 Deaths    City 1 cases  City 2 Deaths   City 2 cases
2011     237                1124             10            1226
2012     228                1030             26           1181
2013     1500              6061             10           1122
2014     528                2320             32           1173
2015     645                3024             11           1232
```

Comment: I am not sure to figure out what your data look like. Maybe it would be benefit to make it clearer. However, if your variable of interest is of the type "time-to-event", then an analysis that takes time into account is definitely more informative than an analysis that only considers the number of cases. One reason for this is that censoring often occurs in such a study and a "time-to-event analysis" is especially designed for that setting...

Comment: In addtion to @marco 's point, I think what you are looking at is a time-series and the independence assumption for observations of t-test may not hold.

Comment: @whuber: Thank you for making the question better by editing it

Comment: @Marco: Thank you for the thought provoking comment. I have added the expected data. Our variable is survived or dead. We have taken care censoring or missing data problem will not happen. I asked the question because Meta-analysis would have the advantage of pooled Relative Risk, cumulative statistics, one study removed data etc. Kindly comment also on this.

Comment: @suncoolsu: Thank you for the great comment. Since my knowledge of statistics is poor, may be my direction of thinking is inappropriate. The problem with time series is the interference by unknown variables. I asked the question because Meta-analysis would have the advantage of pooled Relative Risk, cumulative statistics, one study removed data etc. Kindly comment also on this.

Comment: Do you have, like in your previous question, the information on mortality before start of treatment?

Comment: @SheldonCooper: Yes. I have an idea how the data would look like partially. I entered those data in the question.

Comment: I meant the data on mortality without any treatment, or with treatment when the same drug was used in both cities. The reason I ask is that with just the current data you cannot distinguish between two possibilities. One possibility is that the drug in city 2 is better, another possibility is that the drug is no better, but something else causes the patients to do better -- maybe weather or overall hospital quality or something else.

Comment: @SheldonCooper: Thank you for asking for the clarification.The drugs are different. All other known factors are same. The cities are 1000 Kilometers apart.

Comment: If you can just claim that all other factors are the same, then it's fine to just do a t-test year-by-year or on all 5 years together. This is OK if this is just homework. If this is a real study and real data, then keep in mind that a lot of people will refuse to just believe that all other factors are the same. You will have to convince them somehow. In your previous question you had some pre-intervention data to convince them. Do you have something similar here?

Comment: @SheldonCooper: I am amazed at your speed of response. Thank you so much. I can get pre-invention data. I will take your advice of doing t-test. Kindly clarify one more thing for my benefit. Why Meta-analysis cannot be used? Meta-analysis would have the advantage of pooled Relative Risk, cumulative statistics, one study removed data etc in addition to relative risk year wise. I have not understood why nobody commented on that. Please be frank and tell me if I am wrong. I want to learn.

Comment: @DrWho Meta analysis is for combining results from multiple independent studies that have already been performed and published.  This is not such a situation.  (That's why I originally removed the meta-analysis tag from your question, because it will only mislead people who truly are concerned about meta analysis.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data are categorical, a t test is likely inappropriate for any parameter I can think you might want to do inference on. Here is a brief intro to a very similar problem as yours:

http://walkerbioscience.com/word-files/Categorical%20data.doc

Comment: Thank you very much. I will go though it and get back. i will have to search for the power point file mentioned in that document.

Comment: Thank you very much for the simple but useful reference.